# button with nested ul clases yii framework

Tags: php, widget, yii2

I would like to this, but with yii framework:

```
 <span class="btn default btn-file">
    <span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span>
    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
    <input type="file" name="..."></input>
 </span>
```

trying to do this way but doesn't work;

```
echo Button::widget([
    'label' => 'Select Image',
    'options' => ['class' => 'btn default btn-file'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'fileinput-new'],
]);
```

I'm very newbie in yii framework and I've been spending some time trying to do this but without success. Anyhelp would be very apreciated

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: to output with yii the same html code writen below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The make this input, cou can use either an [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html) (if you have a model) like this:

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'attribute')->fileInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit') ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Or the [Html helper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html) (if you don't want a model):

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>

<?php $form = Html::beginForm(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= Html::fileInput('...') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit') ?>
    </div>

<?php Html::endForm() ?>
```

I believe you won't have problem adapting the style after reading the docs. Both have the `label` method that allows you to edit the label as you want. Let me know if i wasn't clear on something.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?= Html::a('label', ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

hope it will works as you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use file field in the yii2. Create a form and place your field in the form.

```
    <?php
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    ?>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelobj, 'fieldname')->fileInput() ?>

        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit')?>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```